# Multiple subnets internet access

Tags: router, subnet, ubiquiti

I have a EdgeMax Router X and I got the basic to work.
The subnet for the default is 192.168.178.1

My wifi access points have the option for guest networks.
Those however are on a seperate subnet 192.168.179.1

This didn't seem like a problem to me but the 179 subnet doesn't seem to be getting internet access.

Who should I give the 179 subnet internet access? In doing so will it also be able to communicate with the 178?

I tried to add a manual ip to the 'switch0' interface in my router (so both 178 and 179 are configured there) but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

[image: diagram]
[image: table]

Comment: Please post the configuration of your router.  you will likely have to configure VLAN trunking on your router for the guest network.

Comment: Not sure how to post any. It hasn't got much configuration yet. Basically only a DHCP for 192.168.178.0/24 and a switch interface.

Comment: You can edit your post to insert it.  Use the "preformatted" text option.

Comment: What configuration(s) would you like to see?

Comment: All of it.  especially the interface and vlan configurations.  We also need to know more about your access point configuration.

Comment: See edit. Not sure if thats everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51317/discussion-between-john-and-ron-trunk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of what you need to do are too involved for a post here, but these are the high level steps:

1. Create two VLANs on your switch- one for users and one for guests
2. Create a trunk port on the link between your switch and router to
   tag the VLANs
3. Create subinterfaces on your router-- one for each VLAN: 178 and 179
4. Create a new DHCP scope for your guest network
5. Apply an access control list on your router to block guests from
   reacing your internal network.